# Determine f with Laurent expansion at pole

Tags: complex-analysis

### Let f meromorphic everywhere including infinity. The poles of f are just 1, 2 and $\infty$. If the main part of Laurent expansion of f at these three points are respectively $1/(z-1)$, $1/(z-2)+1/(z-2)^2$, and $z+z^2$, adding that $f(0)=0$. Now determine f.

Firstly f must be $f=g/h$, where g, h are polynomials. Then $h=(z-1)(z-2)^2$, and $deg(g)=2+1+2=5$. And g has no constant terms. Then $f=(a_5z^5+a_4z^4+a_3z^3+a_2z^2+a_1z)/(z-1)(z-2)^2$

Then I was stuck how to determine $a_i$?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not difficult to continue. Just use the formula to calculate the coefficients of Laurent expansion at each point and compare with the question, then we got the answer of f.